# Jupyter notebook kernel not seen by 'conda info -e'

Tags: installation, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

Using:

```
/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter kernelspec list
```

I get:

```
  python3                 /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/resources
  ir                      /opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
  apache_toree_pyspark    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_pyspark
  apache_toree_sql        /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_sql
  sparktest_scala         /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/sparktest_scala
```

But when using:

```
conda info -e
```

I get:

```
base                  *  /opt/anaconda3
py35-Spark               /opt/anaconda3/envs/py35-Spark
```

In my notebook I only see the Kernels (python3, ir, Aapache...) I do not see the new environments I set up. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
source activate py35-Spark
```

Then ran:

```
jupyter notebook
```

This will run a new Jupiter notebook instance, so when I go to the browser and open the notebook it uses my conda environment that I set up. I believe there is a way to use ipython kernel instead.